# React / Material-ui pagination component works locally but not on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, material-ui, next.js

Can anyone help with this issue I'm having?

- [x] The issue is present in the latest release.
- [x] I have searched the issues of this repository and believe that this is not a duplicate.

#### Current Behavior

- I am using @material-ui/core: 4.11.2 and @material-ui/lab: 4.0.0-alpha.57
- Pagination works locally but doesn't work at all after building and deploying to the server
- On the server version, I get this error in the browser's console:

`Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function at onClick (7f64add...e1.js:formatted:425)`

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OitMP.png)

When I click on the link (7f64add...e1.js:formatted:425), I get this:

```
ActionsComponent: function(e) {
    var t = e.count
        , a = e.onChangePage;
    return H("div", {
        className: c.root
    }, H(v.a, {
        onClick: function(e) {
            a(e, 0)
        },
        disabled: 0 === r,
        "aria-label": "first page"
    }, "rtl" === l.direction ? H(B.a, null) : H(T.a, null)), H(v.a, {
        onClick: function(e) {
            a(e, r - 1)
        },
        disabled: 0 === r,
        "aria-label": "previous page"
    }, "rtl" === l.direction ? H(A.a, null) : H(N.a, null)), H(v.a, {
        onClick: function(e) {
            a(e, r + 1)
        },
        disabled: r >= Math.ceil(t / o) - 1,
        "aria-label": "next page"
    }, "rtl" === l.direction ? H(N.a, null) : H(A.a, null)), H(v.a, {
        onClick: function(e) {
            a(e, Math.max(0, Math.ceil(t / o) - 1))
        },
        disabled: r >= Math.ceil(t / o) - 1,
        "aria-label": "last page"
    }, "rtl" === l.direction ? H(T.a, null) : H(B.a, null)))
},
```

With this part highlighted:

```
onClick: function(e) {
    a(e, r + 1)
},
```

#### Expected Behavior

- It should work the same way as it does locally

#### Steps to Reproduce

- This is a closed source project from work so it's not possible to reproduce

#### Environment

- I am using react: 16.14.0 and next: 9.5.5 and Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue fixed

I have found the fix for this issue here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/27192

It is explained at the top of the page, and is as follows:

> While prop deprecation is intended to be a non-breaking change, there
> is a corner case in TablePagination where renaming the onChangePage
> prop breaks existing code. Specifically, using TablePagination with a
> custom ActionsComponent is broken because the prop provided to the
> custom ActionsComponent has changed from onChangePage -> onPageChange.